# type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<dynamic>' getting data from Firebase

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

I'm retrieving data from Firebase Storage and Firestore, to show the items in a list with the icon (if the item is a file) or the image (if is image). The problem is, If I get all the images in one time it doesn't load all.. It loads at maximum 20 and crashes due to memory leaking. So My idea is to do a list which gets 10 elements by time, and when the user scroll down to the bottom of the results, it loads more 10 and subsequently. But, I was using Future builder and with it I cant update the list when I need and the problem continues, so now, I'm trying to get in a stream and show with a StreamBuilder to be able to update the list dynamically.

this is my controller:

```dart
loadList(String submenu, [int limit]) async {
    var parts = submenu.split('/');
    var pathSlashless = parts[0].trim();
    var subPathSlashless = parts.sublist(1).join('/').trim();

    var snapshot = await _storage.ref().child("/${submenu}");
    var retorno = await snapshot.listAll();
    List<ItemLab> conteudo = [];

    if(subPathSlashless.isEmpty || subPathSlashless == null){
      retorno.prefixes.forEach((element) {
        conteudo.add(
          ItemLab(
            tipo: 'PASTA',
            elemento: element,
          ),
        );
      });
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < retorno.items.length ; i++){
      var url = await retorno.items[i].getDownloadURL();
      conteudo.add(
        ItemLab(
          tipo: 'FILE',
          elemento: retorno.items[i],
          imageUrl: url,
        ),
      );

      if(limit != null){
        if(conteudo.length > limit){
          hasMore = true;
          return Stream.value(conteudo);
        }else{
          hasMore = false;
          print("less than 9");
        }
      }
    }

    try {
      if(subPathSlashless.isNotEmpty){
        print(subPathSlashless);
        List items;
        await databaseReference
            .collection("lab_${pathSlashless}_url")
            .snapshots().forEach((element) {
              element.docs.forEach((f) {
                if(f.data()['videos'] != null){
                    items == null ? items = f.data()['videos'] :
                    items.addAll(f.data()['videos']);
                  };
                  print("ITEMS :::: >>> ${items}");
              });
        });


        for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i ++){
          //print(items[i]);
          conteudo.add(
            ItemLab(
              tipo: 'VIDEO',
              elemento: null,
              video: items[i],
            ),
          );
        }

      }else{
        await databaseReference
            .collection("lab_${pathSlashless}_url")
            .snapshots().forEach((element) {
          element.docs.forEach((f) {
            if(f.data().isNotEmpty){
              print(f.data());
              if(f.data().keys.contains("videos")){
                conteudo.add(
                  ItemLab(
                      tipo: 'PASTA',
                      pastaVideo: findFolderName(f.reference.path)
                  ),
                );
              }else{
                conteudo.add(
                  ItemLab(
                    tipo: 'VIDEO',
                    elemento: null,
                    video: f.data(),
                  ),
                );
              }
            }
          });
        });
      }


    }catch(e){
      print(e);
    }

    pathSlashless = null;
    subPathSlashless = null;
    conteudo = checkDuplicateFolder(conteudo, submenu);
    return Stream.value(conteudo);
  }
```

And here my list:

```
return StreamBuilder(
      stream: ctrl.loadList(submenu),
      builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
```

But, if I run this code  it throws this error:

> type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Stream'

How  Can I handle that to be able to update the list dynamically using a stream instead of a Future

Comment: This is a case of needing to know what you are actually trying to do to know how to answer your question. A method that is marked as `async` must return a `Future`, and you are trying to feed it into a `StreamBuilder` which needs a `Stream`. But which direction you need to go in order to fix this depends on what you are trying to do. If you need to return a `Stream`, use `async*`, but if you are actually trying to return a `Future`, then use a `FutureBuilder` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't await .snapshots(), as it returns stream, you can change it to get. Also learn more about flutter firebase realtime and normal use case, check the [flutter fire docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/)

```
loadList(String submenu, [int limit]) async {
    var parts = submenu.split('/');
    var pathSlashless = parts[0].trim();
    var subPathSlashless = parts.sublist(1).join('/').trim();

    var snapshot = await _storage.ref().child("/${submenu}");
    var retorno = await snapshot.listAll();
    List<ItemLab> conteudo = [];

    if(subPathSlashless.isEmpty || subPathSlashless == null){
      retorno.prefixes.forEach((element) {
        conteudo.add(
          ItemLab(
            tipo: 'PASTA',
            elemento: element,
          ),
        );
      });
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < retorno.items.length ; i++){
      var url = await retorno.items[i].getDownloadURL();
      conteudo.add(
        ItemLab(
          tipo: 'FILE',
          elemento: retorno.items[i],
          imageUrl: url,
        ),
      );

      if(limit != null){
        if(conteudo.length > limit){
          hasMore = true;
          return Stream.value(conteudo);
        }else{
          hasMore = false;
          print("less than 9");
        }
      }
    }

    try {
      if(subPathSlashless.isNotEmpty){
        print(subPathSlashless);
        List items;
        (await databaseReference
            .collection("lab_${pathSlashless}_url")
            .get()).docs.forEach((f) {
                if(f.data()['videos'] != null){
                    items == null ? items = f.data()['videos'] :
                    items.addAll(f.data()['videos']);
                  };
                  print("ITEMS :::: >>> ${items}");
              });


        for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i ++){
          //print(items[i]);
          conteudo.add(
            ItemLab(
              tipo: 'VIDEO',
              elemento: null,
              video: items[i],
            ),
          );
        }

      }else{
        (await databaseReference
            .collection("lab_${pathSlashless}_url")
            .get()).docs.forEach((f) {
            if(f.data().isNotEmpty){
              print(f.data());
              if(f.data().keys.contains("videos")){
                conteudo.add(
                  ItemLab(
                      tipo: 'PASTA',
                      pastaVideo: findFolderName(f.reference.path)
                  ),
                );
              }else{
                conteudo.add(
                  ItemLab(
                    tipo: 'VIDEO',
                    elemento: null,
                    video: f.data(),
                  ),
                );
              }
            }
          });
      }


    }catch(e){
      print(e);
    }

    pathSlashless = null;
    subPathSlashless = null;
    conteudo = checkDuplicateFolder(conteudo, submenu);
    return conteudo;
  }
```

And the list

```
return FutureBuilder(
      future: ctrl.loadList(submenu),
      builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
```

Comment: But I want to return a Stream to be able to dynamically modify the list... You could help?

Comment: Check the comments, please